# Children's book about boy who rescues alien babies

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, childrens-novel

OK, maybe somebody here can help me out on this one, because I've scoured the Internet for this book with no luck. It was a long-ish picture book (more words than pictures) about a kid who lived on a spaceship with his family.

They landed on a planet and while the kid was exploring, he heard a telepathic distress call that led him to a cave. Inside the cave he found an alien creature that had been trapped under a pile of rocks. The creature was dying, and it asked the boy to care for its children, so he took the alien babies back to his spaceship.

Later, the family's spaceship was boarded by a somewhat sinister other group (I remember the picture of their much larger and more threatening ship dwarfing the family's ship), and he had to keep the aliens hidden from them. I don't remember how it ended.

I read it in the early 80s but the book could've been published a decade before. The text was in English. I vaguely remember the book being a small light blue hardcover. It was probably no more than 20 or maybe 30 pages.